# Downgrading NTFS version

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-vista, filesystems, ntfs

I've created NTFS partition under Windows 8.1. Disk is not recognized by Windows Vista now. How can I downgrade NFTS version to make it mountable under both win 8.1 and Vista?

Comment: Is the volume on a flash drive? Also try running an antivirus scan on the Vista installation to see if any malware is interfering.

Comment: No, it's SATA hdd. single partition, MBR I guess. Linux detects and mounts partition (with --delete-hiberfile or -o ro). Vista is fresh installation. It didn't detect disk properly since first boot

Answer (score 1):

The latest [NTFS version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) (v3.1) is compatible with Windows XP and later, so your problem does not stem from NTFS version. I'm suspecting your partition is not receiving a volume letter automatically in Windows Vista. In Vista, press `Win` + `R` and open `diskmgmt.msc`. Here right click the partition and choose `Change Drive Letter and Paths...` then `Add` and choose a drive letter.

Comment: Vista detects Disk but asks me if I want to format it.